# Escaping Lucene Characters using Javascript Regex

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, lucene

I'm using elasticsearch in a NodeJS project, which is breaking upon entering one of the Lucene keywords into the search box. I'm looking for a simple implementation to escape their special characters. Is regex the best way? I've been fiddling with the regex for a bit now, and felt as if there were probably others that have already gone through this process.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just needed to fiddle more.

```
var escaped = query.replace(/([\!\*\+\&\|\(\)\[\]\{\}\^\~\?\:\"])/g, "\\$1");
```

Globally replace all instances of the chars lucene would yell about with their escaped version.

Comment: Does it handle  && and || by \& and \|

Comment: @sunitj you can check full reserved characters from https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.6/query-dsl-query-string-query.html#_reserved_characters

Comment: Note that this regex will not catch backslash (\\), front slash (/), or minus (-)

Comment: The above answer escapes Lucene special chars, but Elastic has some more which are not included here. See below answer

Answer (score 7):

I updated this to include all elasticsearch & Lucene reserved characters:

```
var pattern = /([\!\*\+\-\=\<\>\&\|\(\)\[\]\{\}\^\~\?\:\\/"])/g;

var str = "}the+S+entence you want]]to e*scape"

str = str.replace(pattern, "\\$1");
```